# Transpose SQL table when the value is text

Tags: sql, sql-server, transpose

I have a table containing a series of survey responses, structured like this:

```
Question Category | Question Number | Respondent ID | Answer
```

This seemed the most logical storage for the data.  The combination of `Question Category`, `Question Number`, and `Respondent ID` is unique.

Problem is, I've been asked for a report with the `Respondent ID` as the columns, with `Answer` as the rows.  Since `Answer` is free-text, the numeric-expecting `PIVOT` command doesn't help.  It would be great if each row was a specific `Question Category` / `Question Number` pairing so that all of the information is displayed in a single table.

Is this possible?  I'm guessing a certain amount of dynamic SQL will be required, especially with the expected 50-odd surveys to display.

Comment: Can you post some sample data and the desired result?  A `PIVOT` uses an aggregate function, this is not restricted to numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

I think this task should be done by your client code - trying to do this transposing on SQL side is not very good idea. Such SQL (even if it can be constructed) will likely be extremely complicated and fragile.

First of all, you should count how many distinct answers are there - you probably don't want to create report 1000 columns wide if all answers are different. Also, you probably want to make sure that answers are narrow - what if someone gave really bad 1KB wide answer?

Then, you should construct your report (would that be HTML or something else) dynamically based on results of your standard, non-transposed SQL.

For example, in HTML you can create as many columns as you want using `<th>column</th>` for table header and `<td>value</td>` for data cell - as long as you know already how many columns are going to be in your output result.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it seems that the problem is the number of columns.  You don't know how many respondents there are.

One idea would be to concatenate the respondent ids.  You can do this in SQL Server as:

```
select distinct Answer,
       (select cast(RespondentId as varchar(255))+'; '
        from Responses r2
        where r2.Answer = r.Answer
        for xml path ('')
       ) AllResponders
from Responses r
```

(This is untested so may have syntax errors.)

Answer (score 0):

If reporting services or excel power pivot are possibilities for the report then they could both probably accomplish what you want easier than a straight sql query. In RS you can use a tablix, and in power pivot a pivot table. Both avoid having to define your pivot columns in an sql pivot statement, and both can dynamically determine the column names from a tabular result set.